# Excel template for creating/retrieving/updating defects in quality center

Tags: quality-center, excel

Has anyone tried using an Excel template/macro for updating defects in Quality Center?

Currently, I can use the Excel add-in to create new bug reports and then upload it to QC. But afterwards, I'd have to maintain it in QC. If I could pull the data back into Excel, then modify from there and then re-upload, that would make things easier.

(Excel is for folks outside the development team (e.g., during UAT) who provide us with bug reports).

Answer (score 2):

couple of points/questions

1) what number of defects are we talking about ? If it's UAT and you are getting too many defects to enter manually then maybe you have other problems ?
:)

2) Maintaining the defects in QC means there is a history behind them, doing it in Excel loses that. So *maybe* you gain from ease of use by using Excel but you could lose out by not having the defect history

I'd rather have 'one version of the truth' and keep QC maintained

Comment: Re: (1) For the recent set of comments that came in, there were 20+ but after weeding them out for duplicates and non-issues, only 2 merit actual fixing. I'm thinking about just logging only those that would require change.